# changing the background of a view inside my relativelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml, android-gridview

I'm having trouble with this layout that is a item in my grid adapter.

I'm using caldroid

I inflate my cell layout in the getview:

R.layout.calendar_view_date_cell.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rlCalendarViewCell"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white1"
 >



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCalendarDayNr"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="10"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/vCellBorder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/selected_border" >
</View>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to use the view that is inside the relativelayout for a border background.

I'm using this method to try and change the background of the cell (to show that this cell of the calendar is the one that has been pressed).

```
 @Override
 public void onSelectDate(Date date, View view) {
      View vCellBorder = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.vCellBorder);
      vCellBorder.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_border);

      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+(date),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
```

The weird thing is, in my date_cell preview I can already see the selected border. But when I run my app, I only see the background of the Relativelayout (color/white1).

If I change my method to:

```
 @Override
 public void onSelectDate(Date date, View view) {

      view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_border);

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+(date),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
```

This up here works. But I dont want it like this, because I want the ability to change different backgrounds for the different layers of the layout.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is because the base class view doesn't know how to layout properly.

I would change the View to an ImageView and place it before the textview in the layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlCalendarViewCell"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white1"
    >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/vCellBorder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/selected_border" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCalendarDayNr"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="10"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also in the code i would hide/unhide the view rather than changing its drawable

so

```
@Override
public void onSelectDate(Date date, View view) {
  View vCellBorder = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.vCellBorder);
  vCellBorder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+(date),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and obviously the view would start as GONE or INVISIBLE

Answer (score 0):

My view was getting 0dp width and height. So thats why the background was not showing. 
In the end I changed my view into a linearlayout and put my textview inside of it. and match_parent is working now. The 0dp was giving me the hint.